# Google OAuth2 sample not working?

Tags: c#, google-oauth

Im trying to learn how to use the google API and I've started with a sample that can be found here: 
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/dotnet

I believe I've followed the instructions exactly and I've copy pasted all the code, but I cant get it to work.

If I debug it Visual Studio ask me for the location of GoogleClientSecrets.cs when I reach the GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync method.

If I just continue the code throws an HttpListenerException with the message (translated from Swedish) "Supplied network name has wrong format". The error code is 1214.

I guess it should open the browser at this point, but it doesnt, could that be the issue?

This is all new to me, so Im have a hard time finding a solution. I've been googleling for a solution for quite some time now.

Any suggestions would be very much appriciated.

This is the code in its entirety:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DriveQuickstart
{
    class Program
    {
        static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly };
        static string ApplicationName = "Drive API Quickstart";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }

        // Create Drive API service.
        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });

        // Define parameters of request.
        FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
        listRequest.MaxResults = 10;

        // List files.
        IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute()
            .Items;
        Console.WriteLine("Files:");
        if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", file.Title, file.Id);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No files found.");
        }
        Console.Read();

    }
  }
```

}

Comment: Anyone?
Im going crazy over here.By googleling and testing things for a while I mean every night for a few days...
Im going crazy over here...

Answer (score 0):

Allright, I dont have an answer to why this was not working, but I've found another way: Skip the Drive API and go for the GData api.

A sample that worked flawless for me can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?hl=en